# Question about if statement if not thing is specified after it?

Tags: python, if-statement, scope

I wanted to ask three things. Firstly, for the 10th line, is this an 'else' statement? It doesn't seem to be the case- if it not, what purpose does it serve?

Secondly, for the 8th line, are we saying that if 'val' is in the list char_set, then return False? And generally speaking is this how we would write this?

Lastly, for line 5, what does [False for _ in range(128)] do? Thanks!

```
 def unique(string):
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False

    char_set = [False for _ in range(128)]
    for char in string:
        val = ord(char)                 
        if char_set[val]:          
            return False
        char_set[val] = True      

    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer this in chronological order (of code execution):

- Line 5, `[False for _ in range(128)]` creates a list of 128 `False` values. This is list comprehension, which can be rewritten as follows:

```py
char_set = []
for _ in range(128):
    char_set.append(False)
```

The `_` means read the value from the iterator (`range` object), and discard it.

- Line 8: `val` is the `ord` of a character, meaning a number. `char_set[val]` gives us the element at index `val`, which is initialized as `False`. During your code (line 10, specifically), this might be overwritten to be a `True`. The `if` statement here checks if the value in that index is `True`.
- Line 10: it's not an `else` statement, albeit in this case it works the same. In this code, if the condition in line 8 does not meet, then the code execution flow skips like 9 and "falls through" to line 10, and life goes on. If the condition in line 8 meets (i.e. `char_set[val]` is `True`), then the line 9 gets executed, and the `return` statement ends the function call abruptly while returning `False` as its result.

Comment: also `[False for _ in range(128)]` can be simplified to `[false] * 128`

Comment: @Hadrian in this case yes, because `bool` is immutable, but otherwise aliasing happens.